# capture bash output values inside perl script

Tags: bash, perl

I have a bash script that sets two variables to values (not a STDOUT) . I want to store those variables inside a perl script.

Sorry dont have example.. but this is the requirement. any thoughts please

In shell script i am doing something like this

```
source <Script Name> <Variable1> <Variable2>
Value1=$output1
Value2=$output2
```

=====================
I want to do same inside perl

Tried

```
system("sh <Script> <Variable1> <Variable2>");
$Value1 = "$output1";
$Value2 = "$output2";
print $Value1
```

Getting Blank

Comment: Is 'output1' just the name of a variable internal to the script?  You'll need to communicate it somehow, probably by writing its value to a stream.  Variables internal to the script will not be directly available to its caller.

Comment: so the shell script `<Script Name>` sets the variables `$output1` and `$output2` ?

Comment: @Kris :First of all, that is no bash involved in your code (you explicitly run your script with `sh`), so I suggest to remove the _bash_ tag. For sending values from your bash script back to Perl, you can use either stdout, or an external file, or maybe a bidirectional pipe. In all cases, you have to parse the output from your script.

Answer (score 3):

To build on the answer by @Snorik, here is one way you can do it:

```
system 'bash', '-c', 'source xyz.sh; echo -n $output1 >1.txt; echo -n $output2 >2.txt';
my $output1 = `cat 1.txt`;
my $output2 = `cat 2.txt`;
```

Comment: Should be i.e. `echo -n "$output1" >1.txt`, to preserve the number of spaces in the variable.

Comment: Thank you i wrote a wrapper to the shell script and redirect the output to file and then i will use that file in perl script

Comment: can you answer your own question please?

Answer (score 1):

As Bash doesnt allow to use actual return values, the easiest way is the bash script to write each value to a file and then read each value from the file.

Have a look at [this](https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-read-file/)

Comment: Unfortunately i dont have access to the bash script, all that i can do is to capture the variables and use it